# Open app when button is clicked I want to open the Gmail app when I click the button. I am using the url launcher

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to open the Gmail app when I click the button. I am using the url launcher.

```
         `InkWell(
          child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: const [
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
              height: 60.0,
            ),
            Text(' "/Open Email/" ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
          ]),
          onTap: () {
            const url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox';
            launchURL(url);
          }),`
```

***When I click this its open the web instead of the app***

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```
const url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox';
```

to

```
const url = 'mailto:${your_receiver_email}';
```

Answer (score 1):

A utils class for sending email, this class can be used for opening whats app, call, message, etc.

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as UL;

class Utils {
  static Future<void> sendEmail(
      {String email, String subject = "", String body = ""}) async {
    String mail = "mailto:$email?subject=$subject&body=${Uri.encodeFull(body)}";
    if (await UL.canLaunch(mail)) {
      await UL.launch(mail);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Unable to open the email");
    }
  }
}
```

Call the method from any class with a click of a button.

```
import 'utils.dart';

void onOpenMailClicked() async {
  try {
       await Utils.sendEmail(
       email: "optional@email.com",
       subject: "Optional",
       );
       } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("sendEmail failed ${e}");
       }
}
```

You need to provide queries for android on the manifest file.

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.example">
       
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
      </intent>
  </queries>
   <application .............
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Andriod_intent_plus` for Android and `url_launcher` for iOS you can achieve this.

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
   final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
           action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
           category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL',
  );
  
  intent.launch().catchError((e) {});
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  launch('message://').catchError((e) {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri gmailUrl = Uri.parse('mailto:test@example.org?subject=Greetings&body=Hello%20World');

InkWell(
          child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: const [
            SizedBox(
              width: 30.0,
              height: 60.0,
            ),
            Text(' "/Open Email/" ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                )),
          ]),
          onTap: () {
            _launch(gmailUrl);
          }),
```

and it’s `_launch` function:

```
    Future<void> _launch(Uri url) async {
    await canLaunchUrl(url)
        ? await launchUrl(url)
        : _showSnackBar('could_not_launch_this_app'.tr());
      }
```